# How to test if a vector3 is inside a cube that is rotated around a specific point

Tags: vectors

I am working on a game and have the following information

Player Position - Vector3
Player Rotation - float (Radiant)
Enemy Location - Vector3
Player attack box - length, width, height

What I need to do it test if the Enemy Location is inside of the player attack box. I know somehow I would either have to rotate the attack box around the player or rotate the enemy location around the player then test it. The rotation is only left to right no up and down. That is why it is a single Radiant value.

I have tried to code the rotation of both the player attack box and the enemy but I feel like I do not have enough knowledge about vector math to properly come up with a solution.

Comment: If your rotation in $\theta$ wrt the $x$-axis then rotate the (enemy - position) vector by $-\theta$. In this new system the box is aligned with the axes and checking that the enemy is inside the box is simple (just an if test for each of the components).

Comment: If you have the normals to the cube’s faces, which can be computed from the player position and rotation, you can do this with a fairly simple range check. What, though, does “player rotation” measure? Without some other assumptions, which you haven’t explained here, a single number isn’t nearly enough information to specify a rotation in 3-D.

Comment: The rotation is based on the players looking direction. So facing right would be 0. @amd

Comment: This would be much easier for people here if you included a sketch (forgetting about the $z$ direction for simplicity) of your coordinate system with the position, the enemy, a rotation and how the box is defined.